# Coming from Ruby: How to move a static method into abstract class in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, abstract-class, static-methods, super

I have two classes, each with a method `build` that returns a new instance of that respective class:

```js
class Foo {
  static build() {
    return new Foo();
  }
}

class Bar {
  static build() {
    return new Bar();
  }
}
```

The actual implementation is more complex. However, I tried to remove the duplication by moving the implementation into an abstract class, but I couldn't figure out how to implement it:

```js
abstract class Base {
  static build() {
    return // <- ???
  }
}

class Foo extends Base {
}

class Bar extends Base {
}
```

Furthermore I'd like to be able to override `build` within `Foo` and / or `Bar`:

```js
class Bar extends Base {
  static build() {
    instance = super(); // <- couldn't get this working
    // do something with instance
    return instance;
  }
}
```

Maybe my approach is just plain wrong. In Ruby, I'd write:

```rb
module M
  def build
    new
  end
end

class Foo
  extend M
end

class Bar
  extend M
end
```

And to override `build`:

```rb
class Bar
  extend M
  def self.build
    instance = super
    # do something with instance
    instance
  end
end
```

How can I achieve something along these lines in TypeScript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Amid's answer is great, just one problem with it is if `Foo` or `Bar` had any properties of their own, then you will have a compiler error since `Base.build` only returns `Base`. You can introduce a type parameter to fix this:

```
abstract class Base {

    protected static build<T>(cls: { new (): T }): T {
        // common init logic comes here
        return new cls();
    }
}
```

Also, when passing the class to `Base.build`, you can just pass `this` as `this` inside static methods will refer to the current class:

```
class Foo extends Base {

    static build(): Foo {
        const instance = Base.build(this); // `instance` will be typed as `Foo` instead of `Base`
        // do something specific with instance
        return instance;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank's, that is basically what I'm looking for, although I wished that `Base` could infer the concrete class automatically because it extends it.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe something like this?

```
abstract class Base
{
    protected static build(cls: {new(): Base}): Base
    {
        // common init logic comes here
        return new cls();
    }
}

class Foo extends Base
{
    static build(): Foo
    {
        const instance = Base.build(Foo);
        // do something specific with instance
        return instance;
    }
}


class Bar extends Base
{
    static build(): Bar
    {
        const instance = Base.build(Bar);
        // do something specific with instance
        return instance;
    }
}


const foo = Foo.build();
const bar = Bar.build();
```

Comment: Do I have to explicitly pass the class as an argument to `build`?

Comment: I'm afraid - yes.

Answer (score 0):

*[I'm answering my own question here]*

After looking at the generated JavaScript, I realized that `this` is already being passed when invoking a method on the superclass.

Getting the types right was much harder. This eventually worked for me:

```
interface BaseConstructor<T> {
  new(): T;
  build(): T;
}

abstract class Base {
  static build<T extends Base>(this: BaseConstructor <T>): T {
    return new this(); // <- this is either Foo or Bar
  }
}

class Foo extends Base {
}

class Bar extends Base {
}

Foo.build(); // instance of Foo
Bar.build(); // instance of Bar
```